# How to use find to search list of hashmaps

Tags: json, groovy

In groovy I have a list of hash maps.

If I want to search / get a record within this map for one combination of subtype and domain how can i do it? P.s. There will likely be more attributes in the maps but I haven't included them here for simplicity .

```
[{
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_ONE",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_ONE"
}, {
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_TWO",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_TWO"
}, {
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_THREE",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_THREE"
}, {
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_FOUR",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_FOUR"
}]
```

Comment: Have you read about `findAll` and `find`?  Have you searched SO about how to find or filter with Groovy or Java8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below:

- Define a map with search crieteria
- Parse the data with `JsonSlurper`
- Use `find` to search

```groovy
def filterCriteria = [subtype__c: 'SUBTYPE_ONE', domain__c: 'DOMAIN_ONE']

def jsonString = """[{
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_ONE",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_ONE"
}, {
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_TWO",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_TWO"
}, {
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_THREE",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_THREE"
}, {
    "subtype__c": "SUBTYPE_FOUR",
    "domain__c": "DOMAIN_FOUR"
}]"""

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)

println json.find{it == filterCriteria}
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/phRc6D)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = [
    ["subtype": "s1", "domain": "d1"],
    ["subtype": "s2", "domain": "d2"],
]
list.find({ Map<String, String> map -> map["subtype"] == "s1" && map["domain"] == "d1"})
```

If there is a possibility of finding multiple such maps, then use "findAll" instead.

```
List<Map<String, String>> found = list.findAll({ Map<String, String> map -> map["subtype"] == "s1" && map["domain"] == "d1"})
```